# Offline WebApp with Backbone.js

Tags: web-applications, backbone.js

I am learning Backbone.js to develop a Single Page Application. However, I am a little confused with Backbone's architecture for storing Models over the server. I don't want to put/store anything over the server. All I want to achieve is:

- WebApp - able to work offline.
- Fetch financial data using web services and store them for offline access
- Display data from local database

That's all.

Could you please guide me what is the ideal way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Backbone.localStorage](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage) plugin.

Comment: Thanks @ethangnawl for quick response. I'll give it a try today.